# LDAP search only returns 25 users

Tags: active-directory, ldap

If I use ldapsearch on my Active Directory to bring back members of the Engineers team I only see 25 users. However in AD there are almost 50 users in Engineers. What am I doing wrong?

```
ldapsearch -p 389 -h 10.1.2.1 -D "CONTOSO\ADReadOnly" -w ************ -b     "ou=ContosoUsers,dc=CONTOSO,dc=COM" -x "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberof=cn=Engineers,ou=Teams,ou=ContosoUsers,dc=CONTOSO,dc=COM))" | grep sAMAccountName
```

Comment: 25 seems kinda strange but try the -z option with a different value. Have you tried dsquery yet?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you don't have rights to read the group membership information (or other attributes?) of the "missing" objects? Try

`ldapsearch -p 389 -h 10.1.2.1 -D "CONTOSO\ADReadOnly" -w ************ -b     "dc=CONTOSO,dc=COM" -x "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=A_MISSING_USERS_SAM))" *`

Do you see the missing user's sAMAccountName? Do you see ANY attributes? If not, you probably have a permissions issue reading the object's attributes.

Also, are you sure the missing users are all under the `ContosoUsers` OU?